Making a dual power supply (positive and negative) up to ±100v
I want to generate a dual polarity with middle ground adjustable voltage power supply that can give up to ±100 volts and 2 amperes of current.
I searched on the Internet but I didn't find enough resources to do this. The image below is an example of what I want:

*Note that I want to get ±5, ±10, ±20, ..., ±100 volts and maximum 2 amperes, but typically 1 ampere.
Reference: https://www.eleccircuit.com/dual-power-supply-3v5v6v9v1215v-with-lm317lm337/

LM317/337 does not withstand 100 V. How much current do you need?

What power? For such a wide range of voltages the best is to use a multi-tapped transformer.

With +-100 V possible and down to 5 V available, at 2 A you are looking at 2952 = 380+ W of losses in your pass elements. Build a switchmode instead? Buy a lab power supply?

I can't use a lab power supply in my project, I have to build it to use in my customised project

@user23328818 Transformer voltage is set by winding an appropriate number of turns to get the desired voltage. The best thing is to get a multi-tap center-tapped transformer, meaning it will have a center tap and a few different voltage outputs from, for example, 10V to 110V on each end. You don't really need multiple voltage outputs, but if you only have a 110-120V output (peak will be around 170V) and you're only using 5V, the other 165V or 97% of the power will be wasted in heat in the regulating element (transistor or IC regulator) unless you use a switching/PWM type.

@user23328818 In other words, if you're using ±5V at 2A, which is like 10V at 2A and thus 20W total power used in your circuit, your regulator will have to waste up to about 600W at ±150V and 2A, just to give you those 20W, which would be absolutely ridiculous. You definitely need a switching/PWM regulator.

@user23328818 You don’t need to build it and shouldn’t build it. Buy two 100V DC 250W switching power supply modules from any power supply manufacturer. They may be a custom item or may be a stock design. Last thing you want is to design one of those yourself as a beginner. It is hard. It’s probably harder to make a good power supply like this than to do whatever you’ll be doing with those +/-100V in your device. Again, I don’t mean a lab supply. I mean a metal frame switcher, similar to those widely used for 3D printers. Just a higher output voltage. It may even be much cheaper than you think

please edit your question ...  add a reference to the schematic diagram ... it is a requirement of this site

Can you dissipate 380+ W of losses? Can you spend ~100 USD on pass elements and heatsinks? If not, you need to rethink this.

Yes, no problem with power losses

The best thing I can recommend for a beginner is not to play with such high voltage power supply, and to get a factory made one.
Just search "dual channel 100V power supply" and get the one you want.

Or, if the dual-channel version is too niche of a product, just buy two 100V 250W supplies. The extra 50W is imho a minimal amount of sweating for normal use.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica You're right, but it might be worth it the extra money to have a dual supply in a single box. There are even triple output power supplies available. I agree on the extra 50W. I saw some 100 V 3 A models on the net, so that would definitely be enough.

Sorry I've searched for it but there is no power supply module such that in my area, I have to build one

@user23328818 "no power supply module such that in my area" Mouser, DigiKey, RS, Farnell, TMC and others ship all over the world.

@winny Yes, there are even supplies from AliExpress which ships around the world.
